# How to include ext-searchbox.js in my javascript bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-2, ace-editor

Ctrl+F does not work in Ace editor because it can't load ext-searchbox.js. I see  404 when press Ctrl+F.

I found out that ext-searchbox.js is located in node_modules\ace-builds\src folder.

I would like to properly include this extension in my vendor.js bundle.
I have an Angular 2 project with a ASP.NET Core project as a server. My bundler is Webpack 2 and I use [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices). I do not use angular-cli.

Comment: how do you include the ace.js file?, you need to include extensions you want to load the same way

Comment: @auser I added import and it helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component where I use the editor I added two imports:

```
import 'brace';
import 'brace/ext/searchbox';
```

This import let Webpack add searchbox to my bundle.

Comment: Thank @Evgeni. I would like to confirm here that it works.